# How does the react library rerender components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to figure out how the react library rerenders components after updating the `props`. Therefor I kind of monkey patched `ReactDOM.render` method like so:

```
const oldRender = ReactDOM.render

ReactDOM.render = function(){
// ......
console.log("42")
  return oldRender.call(this, ...arguments, () => {
    console.log("done")
    document.dispatchEvent(new Event('react-dom-rendered'))
  })
}
```

This works for the first rendering cylce. But after the `props` of the rendered component changed, the `console.log`s are not printed anymore. In order to figure out why I read in the docs that `ReactDOM.render` will only be called **once**. So I searched through google just like through react's sources but I was not able to find out how react manages to rerender a component after a props update. Could you help me here?

Comment: What do you mean in "How"? Did you read the docs? Are you talking about [Reconciliation](https://reactjs.org/docs/glossary.html#reconciliation)? What kind of answer do you expect?

Comment: @DennisVash thank you very much and yes, i talk about `Reconciliation`. In the very best case I'd love to find the source code where this reconciliation is implemented. I read the docs and I also found something about it but not exactly what i was searching for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ReactDom.render`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#render) called once to mount the component into the DOM.

On state update or on props change, React starts a **Reconciliation** process.

> When a component’s props or state change, React decides whether an actual DOM update is necessary by comparing the newly returned element with the previously rendered one. When they are not equal, React will update the DOM. This process is called “reconciliation”.

In this process, React runs a pretty simple [**diff algorithm**](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html) while traversing a copy of Virtual DOM.

Want to implement the **Reconciliation**? See [Build your own React](https://pomb.us/build-your-own-react/) and its [repo](https://github.com/pomber/didact).

```
function reconcileChildren(wipFiber, elements) {
  let index = 0
  let oldFiber =
    wipFiber.alternate && wipFiber.alternate.child
  let prevSibling = null

  while (
    index < elements.length ||
    oldFiber != null
  ) {
    const element = elements[index]
    let newFiber = null

    const sameType =
      oldFiber &&
      element &&
      element.type == oldFiber.type

    if (sameType) {
      newFiber = {
        type: oldFiber.type,
        props: element.props,
        dom: oldFiber.dom,
        parent: wipFiber,
        alternate: oldFiber,
        effectTag: "UPDATE",
      }
    }
    if (element && !sameType) {
      newFiber = {
        type: element.type,
        props: element.props,
        dom: null,
        parent: wipFiber,
        alternate: null,
        effectTag: "PLACEMENT",
      }
    }
    if (oldFiber && !sameType) {
      oldFiber.effectTag = "DELETION"
      deletions.push(oldFiber)
    }

    if (oldFiber) {
      oldFiber = oldFiber.sibling
    }

    if (index === 0) {
      wipFiber.child = newFiber
    } else if (element) {
      prevSibling.sibling = newFiber
    }

    prevSibling = newFiber
    index++
  }
}
```